# Can I compare array[i] to 'letter'

Tags: c

In the following statement I attempt to scan a word from the user, and compare it to 2 char's. Is this ok? I attempted to delete this question.

```
scanf("%s", Word);

if(Word[j] == 'a' || 'A'){
    

    flag =1;
}
```

Comment: Assuming there is an array Word[10] and using a while does that improve the situation. I

Comment: Delete the question if you want, but don't vandalize it.

Comment: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information

Answer (score 1):

You want to say

```
if(Word[j] == 'a' || Word[j] == 'A'){
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, the expression

```
Word[j] == 'a' || 'A'
```

is interpreted as

```
(Word[j] == 'a') || ('A')
```

In other words, this means "compare `Word[j]` to `'a'`. If they match, great! Otherwise, evaluate the expression `'A'` and see if it's nonzero." That's not what you meant to do, and this expression will as a result always evaluate to true.

To fix this, rewrite the expression as

```
if (Word[j] == 'a' || Word[j] == 'A') {
    ...
}
```

Or, alternatively, as

```
if (tolower(Word[j]) == 'a') {
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
Word[j] == 'a' || Word[j] == 'A'
```

---

`==` is a binary operator, which means it has (exactly) two operands. As such,

```
Word[j] == 'a' || 'A'
```

is equivalent to

```
( Word[j] == 'a' ) || 'A'
```

`||` returns `0` if both of its operands are `0`, `1` otherwise. (It only evaluates its right-hand side operand if necessary.)

Since its right-hand side operand is always true (`'A'` is a number other than zero), the condition will *always* be true.